# Reuse entities and context from EF in SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sqlite-net

I am writing integration tests that are using SQLite and will use EF for testing repositories.

The Data layer has the entities and a DbContext generated by using database first, but it is generated for SQL Server. The Data layer is used by the Repository layer.

The Integration Test layer will have a context but for SQLite strong text, should I recreate the Entities strong text and context on this layer or can I reuse the context and entities from the Data layer?

Comment: Of course you should use the context and entity classes from the data layer. That's the code you want to test. The connection string determines the database the context communicates with.

Comment: @GertArnold, thanks for your comment, but is it possible to take the context from the data layer and use it on SQLite that has the same structure of the SQL Server tables?

Comment: *The connection string determines the database the context communicates with.*